# How to say "at this rate"?

Tags: words, colloquial-language

One of my friends has been making a real effort talking to me in Japanese every day. I wanted to say something like "If we continue at this rate I will be able to speak by Christmas". The dictionary thinks that at this rate is この分。

So my question is, is it natural correct Japanese if I say

> この分に続いたら、クリスマスまで話せるようになるわよ

?

I suspect that not. It feels like there is a word missing like この分のスピードに or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to say "at this rate" in Japanese but the more common ones are:

> 「この調子{ちょうし}だと/なら」、「このペースだと/なら」、「このままいけば」, etc.

Any one of these would fit your sentence with no problem.

Regarding 「この分{ぶん}」, you could use it by adding 「なら」 or 「だと」 to it, but not 「に」 as you formed it.  You cannot say 「この分に続いたら」, though it was a nice try.  You can say 「この分だと」.

Note:  It is 「クリスマスまで**に**」 and not 「クリスマスまで」.

～～まで**に** = by ~~

～～まで = until ~~

Use 「まで」 and you will be saying that you are only allowed to speak Japanese until Christmas.  You can speak Japanese after Christmas, too, you know.

Comment: Thank you, especially for also pointing out the に after the まで！So you would definitely avoid the 続く? I don't know why but I keep using the wrong particles. Like e.g. using the words you gave me in your answer I would produce このペースで続いたら、。。。> . <

Comment: @user213845 "このペースで続いたら" >> You can say このペースで続ければ or 続けたら (using the transitive 続ける/続けた rather than the intransitive 続く/続いた).

Comment: @choco Oh, now I realise it's 続ける　rather than 続く! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I would say

> このまま続ければ、クリスマスまでには話せるようになるわよ

for

> If we continue at this rate I will be able to speak by Christmas.

Caveat："If we continue at this rate" literally (= in a verbatim fashion) translates into "私達がこの速さで(努力を)継続すれば". See 1.1 of this -> http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rate .